# $(document).ready(function () is not working after popup is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will create one page like form.aspx. In that page click on button then open popup as a div tag at same time call

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    id = querySt("i") || "0"; 
    dtl = querySt("dtl") || "0";
    loadDDL();
    getHeader(id);
    loadReport(id);

    $(".modalPopup").draggable({ 
        cancel: ".divTA, .dcmbStatus" 
    });
    $("#modalPopup").center();
    $("#txtActionDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 1,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (n) {
            $("#txtActionDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", n)
        }
    });
    getUsers();
    ko.applyBindings(srcVM, document.getElementById("dvActions"))
});
```

The `document.ready` function is working but problem is that after change any event or any click on this popup nothing work to date picker event means not call `document.ready` function call. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: what code isn't working specifically? ready handler shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: [jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: Hi Meet, I think you don't understand how $(document).ready works. Answer my comment if you want me to explain and fix your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that jQuery `$(document).ready` function will listen the document ready event, and it only trigger once when fire the event.

If you want to bind the `datepicker` dynamically when click the popup or other behavior, use $('popup').on('click') instead, then when you click the popup, it will bind the `datepicker`.

And more likely, you want bind the `datepicker`, really when document ready.That you can render popup at the first time and hide it,then jQuery can bind the datepicker even if it not show.

Wish that could help.